# How to break|break|return in a Haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I want to return all the cubes (x^3) that are less than a parameter Int using a list comprehension.  I have the following:

```
cubesLessThanN :: Int -> [Int]  
cubesLessThanN int = [if x * x * x <= int then x else * | x <- [0..int]]
```

The asterisk is where I am having the problem.  I kinda want to stop processing the loop once the `else` happens.  The final `[list]` should only have the cubes, not the other values of `x`.  I don't care really how it happens, but would like to know the options, and what the differences are (if any).

If I try to return `null`, `Nothing`, `''`, and a few other ones. I know I am supposed to return a type of `int` if I return anything at all.

Comment: Can't you use list comprehension conditions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List comprehensions support *guards*.

```
[x | x <- [0..int], x ^ 3 <= int]
```

Since list comprehensions are sugar for the list monad, this is equivalent to using the `guard` function in a `do` block:

```
do
  x <- [0..int]
  guard (x ^ 3 <= int)
  return x
```

If we desugar this into `>>=` and inline the definitions of `>>=` and `guard`:

```
concatMap (\x -> if x ^ 3 <= int then [x] else []) [0..int]
```

This is akin to a filter.

```
filter (\x -> x ^ 3 <= int) [0..int]
```

Checking the condition will continue (lazily) even after the value of `x ^ 3` exceeds the value of `int`. To prevent that, you can use `takeWhile` because you know that your function is monotonic.

```
takeWhile (\x -> x ^ 3 <= int) [0..int]
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile):

```
cubesLessThanN :: Int -> [Int]
cubesLessThanN int = takeWhile ((<= int) . (^3)) [0..]
```

Comment: Is this considered a list comprehension?

Comment: @chrisFrisina: No, but you can’t do it with just a list comprehension. You can cause the remaining elements to be excluded, but that’s not the same thing (less efficient and doesn’t work on infinite lists). The closest thing would probably be `map fromJust $ takeWhile isJust $ [if x * x * x <= int then Just x else Nothing | x <- [0..]]`.

Comment: To add to minitech's comment, list comprehensions only go so far; when you start doing more complex things, it's better to learn to use the wider variety of things offered in the [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html) library module (like `takeWhile`).

Answer (score 1):

Take a cube root

```
[ x ^ 3 | x <- [ 1 .. ceiling (fromIntegral int ** (1/3)) ], x ^ 3 < int ]
```

For example:

```
λ let int = 1000 in [ x ^ 3 | x <- [ 1 .. ceiling (fromIntegral int ** (1/3)) ], x ^ 3 < int ] :: [Int]
[1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729]
```

Comment: This results in `[0,1,8,27]` for both `27` and `64`.

Comment: Now it’ll include 1000 for anything in (729, 1000).

Comment: minitech: sigh, suppose I'll add the boundary check.